# Mac OS X: making DMG installer. How to install browser plugins with App?

Tags: macos, installation, browser-plugin, dmg

I learned how to make dmg package. But I need to install browser plugins when I install app. How to do this? 1password app's installer can do this. I need to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMG is not applicationa package but a disk image and has no mechanism to run scripts on mount.
You need to create PKG and use postflight script to copy your plugin. You can read more in Apple [Software Delivery Legacy Guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution4/SoftwareDistribution4.pdf)